# Understanding Proof about Continued Fraction convergent sequences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, proof-explanation, continued-fractions

I copied a proof from lecture and don't understand the end of it. It is intro number theory on continued fractions. Hopefully someone can explain it to me

Background: 
The sequences {$h_n$} and {$k_n$} are defined recursively as such.

$h_{-2} = 0 \quad h_{-1} = 1 \quad h_i = a_ih_{-1} + h_{-2}$

$k_{-2} = 1 \quad k_{-1} = 0 \quad k_i = a_ik_{-1} + k_{-2}$

Prop:

$$
    det\begin{vmatrix}
    h_i & h_{i-1} \\
    k_i & k_{i-1} \\
    \end{vmatrix} = (-1)^{i-1}
$$

Proof:

Works for $i=0$ (I'm omitting this part, I understand we need the base case).

(Then the next part is where I get confused)

Suppose true for $i < n$

Then

$$
    det\begin{vmatrix}
    h_n & h_{n-1} \\
    k_n & k_{n-1} \\
    \end{vmatrix} = h_nk_{n-1}-k_nh_{n-1}
= (a_nh_{n-1}+h_{n-2})k_{n-1} - (a_nk_{n-1}+k_{n-2})h_{n-1}
= h_{n-2}k_{n-1}- k_{n-2}h_{n-1}
$$

(Following all the algebra and substitution up to this point.)

Then:

$$ = -(h_{n-1}k_{n-2}-k_{n-1}h_{n-2}) = -(-1)^{n-2} = (-1)^{n-1}$$
By induction hypothesis we are done.

Some questions:

1. How are we done? I don't understand, don't we need to do an $n+1$ case? If someone could also shed light on induction proofs where the induction hypothesis is of the type $i<n$ that'd really help me out. Maybe I'm just missing something or confusing myself.

Comment: We’re assuming it’s true for $n-1$ and showing it’s true for $n$; by the way, I think you meant $n$ not $i$ in the subscripts in the second determinant

Comment: Changes the subscripts in the second det, thank you. 

I just don't understand why we multiply the last part  by $-1$ and how the part inside the brackets  $= -(-1)^{n-2}$

Comment: $h_{n-1}k_{n-2}-k_{n-1}h_{n-2}= (-1)^{n-2}$ is basically the statement (assumed true) for $n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove something by induction, we have to prove it for the base case, say $i=0,$

and then  prove that, if it holds for any $m  ≥  0$, it holds for $m+1.$

Equivalently (replacing $m+1$ with $n$), if it holds for any $n-1\ge0$, it holds for $n$.

So we assume the statement is true for any $n-1$, i.e.,  $h_{n-1}k_{n-2}-k_{n-1}h_{n-2}= (-1)^{n-2}$

and then show that the statement holds for $n$, i.e., $h_nk_{n-1}-k_nh_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$.

I hope this clarifies things for you.